# Why does push_back() create two zeros at the start of the vector

Tags: c++

Considering the following code and input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
     int n;
     cin >> n;
     vector<int> v(n);

     while(n--) {
         int a, b;
         cin >> a >> b;
         v.push_back(a);
         v.push_back(b);
     }

     for(auto item : v)
         cout << item << " ";
     cout << endl;
}
```

Input

```
2
1 2
3 4
```

What i expect as output
`1 2 3 4`

What i get as output
`0 0 1 2 3 4`

What behaviour of vector.push_back() I'm I not understanding?

Comment: ***Why does push_back() create two zeros at the start of the vector*** `vector<int> v(n);`  I assume you typed 2 as the input.

Comment: [Rubber ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know how many items are in the `vector` after `vector<int> v(n);`

Comment: Comment out your `while` loop completely and see what it prints.

Comment: `vector<int> v(n);` creates a vector of `n` zeroes. Either use `vector<int> v;` to create an empty vector, **OR** change the size to `2*n` and replace `push_back`s with `v[i] = ...`.

Comment: You could also change `vector<int> v(n);` to `vector<int> v; v.reserve(n);`

Comment: Don't thank me. Thank HolyBlackCat. They explained it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What behaviour of vector.push_back() I'm I not understanding?

`push_back` does what you expect; the problem is `vector<int> v(n);` where in your example create the vector with `2` elements. Simplest fix is `vector<int> v;`

Answer (score -1):

`push_back()` inserts new element. It does not make an assignment. Note that your vector size was `n` before inserting the new elements using `push_back()`, hence you will have a vector of size of `3n` having `n` leading zeros. Use the following instead:

```
vector<int> v(2*n);
for (size_t i{}; i < n; ++i) {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    v[2*i] = a;
    v[2*i + 1] = b;
}
```

*or*

```
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(2*n);
while (n--) {
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
}
```

Comment: Also `size_t i{};` is strange choice,  will it always be constructed as 0.

Comment: @ user4581301 I didn't notice that I hadn't changed `n` to `2*n` in the first snippet as I did in the second. I have edited it.

Comment: @M.A Yes It's always zero