# C++ Vector and cin

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n,k;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>k;

    vector<int> arr(n);
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>temp;
        arr.push_back(temp);                                                                
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Why element is not storing into a vector? what is going on?

Input:

6 3

1 2 3 4 5 6

Output:

0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Try with this #include<bits/stdc++.h>. Add it.

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is a bad practice and the question is answered in the given link

Comment: Input:
6 3
1 2 3 4 5 6

Output:
0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: There are many answers to ur questions!! See this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63875203/why-does-push-back-create-two-zeros-at-the-start-of-the-vector/63875283#63875283

Comment: @asmmo Ya got it ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this change:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>temp;
    arr[i] = temp; // here is the change
}
```

Why the OP's code isn't working?

`vector<int> arr(n);` created a vector of `n` elements.
`arr.push_back(temp);`  is causing a push of `n` more elements.
So, if you print `2n` length you can see your answer.

```
for(int i=0;i< 2*n;i++){ // here is the change.
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
```

For input 2 2 3 4, you can get output 0 0 3 4.

Instead of pushing `n` more elements, you should set those input `temp` to already allocated memory in a way I've shown above.

Or alternatively, just `push` instead of pre-allocating memory.
Instead of `vector<int> arr(n);` declare as `vector<int> arr;` it should work.

Comment: I know this or other way to do.But question is why  it is not working?

Comment: @Nirajsingh: Edited the post to answer your question.

Comment: Why read into a temporary variable and not just directly into the vector element?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: I just wanted to keep as much code similar as possible to that of OP's. There could be couple of more improvements possible in OP's code but I wanted to stick to the question being asked.